# is it possible to call win form rather than windows login window?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

I just want to know, can we replace standard windows login UI with Win form based UI. Will it run at the time of booting instead of standard login window. If yes which process is needed to call after authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question is tagged with Windows-7,  I think the correct answer is Credentials Provider.  You can find some samples in the Windows SDK.  This MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx) gives a very good introduction and it also provides a sample.  GINA is used only in pre-vista Windows

Comment: But do you think one can write a custom Credentials Provider using managed code? I wonder if this is supported?

Comment: lets say i should use C++ provided MS sample and customize it accordingly. but can I use VC++ windows app as Windows login UI?

Comment: @Simon I didn't try it but I think it's possible because we can implement COM object using C#

Comment: @RAJ I don't think you can use a regular VC++ windows app as Windows login UI.  You need to provide COM components so that the login process render the UI for you.

Comment: @RAJ Sorry, I don't have any better tutorial other than that article.  BTW, I google a bit and found people saying CLR doesn't work in kernel mode.  That means you cannot write it in C#.  I will spend some time doing something on this area later for my own interet.  I think the only way to allow us writing C# extension on Credentials Provider is to have the Credentials Provider talk to a user mode local NT service and the NT service can be written in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. you need to replace the GINA DLL, and you should read more about GINA programming before you do it.

[Customizing GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx)

(edit) and seek more data about win7 (this time they call it "Credential Providers"), as this article is old. most of the biometric systems use this to replace regular authentication, so it should be possible.

Comment: GINAs are deprecated in Vista and Win7, replaced with Credential Providers.  I don't know if it's possible to present UI in a credential provider though.